# Display the top answer from the original question on the duplicate?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Let's say I search something on Google, and the first link is a Stack Overflow question, I click on it, and I find out that the question is a duplicate, without any answers, so I have to click the link on the top to get the answer.

I was thinking, it would be nice if the answer from the original question was automatically displayed on the duplicate, the answer could be selected automatically (top voted or accepted) or by those who marked the question as duplicate.

- If the answer is good enough, I can upvote it
- If the answer isn't, I can click on the link, and see the other answers

Here's a picture to show you what I mean:

[image]

It's just an idea I had, it's maybe a horrible idea, but personally I think it could be interesting.

I think it could be nice for HTML/CSS questions, since many of these questions can be answered quickly.

Comment: That the answer is accepted doesn't mean it is the correct answer.

Comment: what if there is 50+ answers? which is very common for HTML/CSS questions

Comment: @HereticMonkey That's true, but what if users who mark the question as duplicate could choose the most fitting answer?

Comment: That would be much better. I'd love to be able to mark questions as duplicates of an answer. However, that would be unlikely to be acceptable around here, as most people are of the opinion that only exact duplicate questions should be marked as such.

Comment: Just log out and try to go to the page again. Black magic!

Comment: I think that would cause more confusion than it would help. The other answer has been written in the context of another question. Even when the information there also answer your question, it may uses different code/variables/context or whatsoever. It would be better to click on the link, scan the question to get the context and then read the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all this feature-request is already implemented for majority of people who *use* Stack Overflow - anonymous visitors are automatically redirected to the duplicate target.

For the rest who are signed in - yes you have to click on the link to get to the duplicate. Unfortunately there is no existing automatic way to find "the best answer" (either in general or for a particular duplicate). Note that the "accepted" answer is just "OP really liked it" (answer does not even need to be correct), the top voted answer may be completely obsolete and the latest answer could be "I have the same problem too" - so no cheap way to automatically pick one.  Any manual "use that answer when coming from duplicate" could be obsolete pretty soon and actually be worse than checking out current state of the target.

Using second browser where you are not logged in to SO for your searches is easy workaround... also you can't vote on post that way and would miss possibly suggestions in comments on duplicated posts.

---

I personally would love to support some variation of this proposal, but so I have not seen or come up with solution that preserves "keep good answers in one place" and does not involve magic to select most currently appropriate answer.

Comment: I didn't know that anonymous users get automatically redirected, I'm always logged in on SO. I accepted your answer, it explains well the issues related to this implementation, and I understand better now. Thanks, have a nice day.

Answer (score 3):

The current system of duplicates is (for many) clear and familiar. Your mock-up makes it confusing because it’s not clear that the answer is from a different question.

Many answers can’t just be transplanted under another question (even if it’s a duplicate) and still make sense.

Something like “replace the first line of your function with ...“ that was crystal clear when it was written would be confusing if you thought it was referring to a different question. And even if you realized it didn’t belong to that question you would still have to leave the page to see the question it does belong to.

That’s not to say I don’t like the idea, but there hasn’t been a good enough suggestion for the implementation yet. (A similar FR suggested Wikipedia-style hover pop ups but the criticism was that you would need to put too much in there for it to make sense. Still, I liked that suggestion.)